# In osx terminal, how to open EMACS on new window?

Tags: osx, emacs

When I used EMACS installed from macport, I could open EMACS with new window by just clicking icon in applications menu. Since it has problem on loading some packages, however, I removed macport EMACS. Then I reinstalled EMACS from homebrew. Brew version works well with respect to packages. But I don't know how to open it with new window. Now, I just can open EMACS in terminal window. Is there any way to open EMACS on new window without using aquamacs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve this problem myself. First, just uninstall EMACS. Then type

> brew install emacs --with-cocoa

to reinstall EMACS. You don't need to worry about elimination of ~/.emacs.d directory.

Comment: `Error: invalid option: --with-cocoa` :(

Answer (score -1):

I installed directly from https://emacsformacosx.com
and works perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

```
brew cask install emacs
```

will install a Cocoa-based version from https://emacsformacosx.com, which is better supported than the accepted answer's version.